# React JS inline style not applying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

```
render() { 
  const styles = {
    maxHeight: 'auto'
  }
  return (
    <div styleName="sticky-social-share" className={this.state.open ? 'open': null} >
      <ul styleName="sticky-social-share__icons" style={this.state.open ? styles : null}>
```

I was trying to implement inline CSS for the `sticky-social-share__icons` element but it's not working properly.

Comment: CSS max-height property has no `auto` value

Comment: Also, you can avoid ternary conditional operator by using `className={this.state.open && 'open'}` and `style={this.state.open && styles}`. Other than these, your code should work fine.

Comment: @sandddyyyy - That's an answer. :-) Interestingly, [MDN claims it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/max-height), but [I don't see it in CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-max-height) and Chrome says `auto` is an invalid value. Sooraj - Your code works fine with other style values: http://jsfiddle.net/4kw01gdL/

Comment: `max-height` property can only be `auto` in `viewport` at-rule. This is the [actual use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) of `max-height` in usual circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Set height to auto rather than max-height:

```
height: 'auto'
```

`max-height` should have specific value using some measure like `em`, `%`, `px`, etc.

```
height: 'auto',
maxHeight: '300px'
```

As far as I understand, you should be using `min-height`:

```
height: 'auto',
minHeight: '300px'
```

Further, you may avoid ternary operator by using **and** operator:

```
style={this.state.open && styles}
```

This will apply the `styles` object only if `this.state.open` returns truthy value.